# VLAN: No internet access

Tags: vlan

My setup is as follows:

[internet] - Netgear FVS318N Router - Netgear GS752TP Smart Switch

FVS318N port 1 connects to port 39 on GS752 Smart Switch
WNAP210 connects to port 48 on GS752 Smart Switch

On GS752, VLAN10 is set to: port 39 as T, and port 48 as U.

On FVS918, I have configured two subnets with DHCP, one for VLAN1 and another for VLAN10.

Now, if I plug in a laptop to port 48 on the switch (as opposed to the WNAP210), the laptop gets an IP in the VLAN10 range and can browse the internet.

If I plug in the WNAP210, and connect a laptop to it wirelessly, the laptop gets an IP n the VLAN10 range, but can not browse the internet.

The WNAP210 has a System > Advanced page where the option is to set:

- 802.1Q VLAN
- Untagged VLAN (checked or not), with a VLAN ID

I've tried every combination on that page, and still the same result.  Wondering if I need to configure a route on either the FVS318 or the GS752.

**ROUTER**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**SWITCH**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**AP**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

Comment: Please consider adding [more details](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/775); we need to see your AP and switch configurations

Comment: What is the IP address and default gateway address you get on your laptop when you are plugged into the switch?  Is it the same when you are wireless?

Comment: I'll upload screenshots later today.  The FVS318 has an IP of 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.10.1.  The switch has 10.0.0.2.  If I plug in to any port but 48, I get an address of 10.0.0.x with gateway of 10.0.01, on port I get 10.0.10.x with a gateway of 10.0.10.1.    When I plug in the AP, it gets an ip of 10.0.10.x with a gateway of 10.0.10.1.    I have tried setting the Untagged VLAN to checked with a value of VLAN10, as well as unchecked.

Comment: With the AP plugged into port 48, if on the switch, I set port 48's PVID to 1, I get an IP on VLAN1 and can browse the net, etc.  If I revert port 48's PVID to 10, I get the problem I am describing.

Comment: Added screenshots from what I can gather are all of the pages that matter...

Comment: I'm mostly suspicious of the router/firewall.  Based on a quick scan of the manual, I don't think you can set the router ports to do trunking.  You may have to connect two cables to the router, one for each VLAN.  Set router ports 1 and 2 to VLANs 1 and 10, respectively.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, but will give it a go... will update tomorrow!

Comment: I set the router port 1 to VLAN1, and port 2 to VLAN10.  Then what happens is that all machines on the network (wired and wireless) get an IP on the 10.0.10.x subnet and none can access internet.  I even tried setting the port on the switch to where it connect to the router to T and U with no luck.

Comment: Lat's take this one step at a time.  Plug your PC into ports 1 and 2 on the router and verify that you get the correct IP address AND you can reach the internet.  The connect your switch to the ports.  To make it simple, say port 1 on the switch connects to port 1 on the router, and port 2 connects to port 2..  Next, make sure VLAN 1 is untagged on port 1 and vlan 10 is untagged on port 2.  In fact, all your ports on the switch should be untagged.

Comment: Is the laptop via the AP getting a default g/w and dns servers assigned?  What are they?

Comment: Laptop via AP gets gateway of 10.0.10.1 and DNS of 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have a gateway (security appliance / router), a switch, and an access point.  You want 4 VLANs - default, voice, video, and guest.

You need to configure each of these VLANs with a unique subnet and IP address in your gateway.  The IP address assigned to the gateway is the default gateway for each VLAN/subnet.

The switch and AP should have a management IP address assigned to them from the default VLAN/subnet (e.g. 10.0.0.1 in your case) and their default gateway is the IP address of the gateway.

10.0.0.1/24 = gateway
10.0.0.2/24 = switch
10.0.0.3/24 = AP

OK, now: how to connect the gateway and AP to the switch.  Trunk ports are necessary to carry the multiple VLANs to the AP and gateway.  The AP needs to see all VLANs so it can assign clients to either default or guest, as does the gateway (so it can route between the VLANs/subnets).

Configure trunking to both AP and gateway.  802.1q should be an option and your default vlan should be VLAN1.

Your AP will need to have unique SSID's per VLAN/subnet with each it's own security policy.

Your gateway will need to have NAT/PAT enabled.

Does that help?

Comment: I connected the gateway to the switch with a single cable.  On the switch, I set the ports that have the cables to the gateway and AP to T (PVID of port going to gateway = 1 and PVID for port going to AP = 10) for VLAN10.  From VLAN1, everything is OK.  From the laptop connected to the AP n VLAN10, I can ping the gateway, but not the switch or the internet.

Comment: You need to be trunking on both ports - trunking to the gateway and trunking to the AP.  So, there is no single vlan assigned to either of those ports / links.  Those links need to be setup as trunk links.